# ERE version of PCRE regular expression for matching email addresses

Tags: regex

The following Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE) for email addresses:

```
[^<>(){}\\[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@"]+(\\.[^<>(){}\[\]\\\\.,;:\\s@"]+)*@([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}
```

works great with NodeJS (`String.prototype.match`) and `git grep -P`.

I'd like to "downgrade" that from Perl-compatible to extended (ERE) to work with `grep -E`.  My attempt:

```
echo 'teddy@bear.com' | grep -E '[^<>(){}\\[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@"]+(\\.[^<>(){}\[\]\\\\.,;:\\s@"]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}'
```

fails to match the email address.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
grep -E '[^][<>(){}\\.,;:@"[:space:]]+(\.[^][<>(){}\\.,;:@"[:space:]]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}'
```

See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/9w2cSt)

The `]` should be put at the start of the character class, the `[` does not have to be escaped inside a bracket expression, double backslashes must be replaced with single ones. And it is safer to use POSIX character classes, like `[:space:]` instead `\s`.